# The area & center of gravity of a polygon having non-uniform density of vertices? (in Python)

Tags: python, polygon

I would like to calculate the COG of a polygon shaped exactly like the contour map of my town. However, using the available database of borderpoints would produce a rigged result, since some places have much bigger density of borderpoints than others, so the center of gravity would be skewed towards these regions. I tried to equalise the density of vertices by producing this Python code:

```
import numpy as np
punkty = open("borderpoints.txt","r", encoding = "utf8")

tempp = []

a = []
for line in punkty:
    for c in line:
        
        if c != " ":
            tempp.append(c)  
        else:
            p = "".join(tempp)
            a.append(p)
            tempp = []
        
i = 0
x= []
y = []
fx = open("outx1.txt", "w")
fy = open("outy1.txt", "w")
while i<len(a)-1:
    x.append(a[i])
    fx.write(a[i])
    fx.write("\n")
    y.append(a[i+1])
    fy.write(a[i+1])
    fy.write("\n")
    i= i+2

j = 0
jump = 20
newxs = []
newys = []
fnx = open("newxs.txt","w")
fny = open("newys.txt", "w")
while j<len(x):
    L = np.sqrt(pow((float(y[j+1])-float(y[j])),2)+pow((float(x[j+1])-float(x[j])),2))
    n = jump*L
    interval = (float(y[j+1])-float(y[j]))/n
    k = 1
    slope = (float(x[j+1])-float(x[j]))/(float(y[j+1])-float(y[j]))
    inters = float(x[j+1])-slope*float(y[j+1])
    while k<n+1:
        g = float(y[j])+k*interval
        newxs.append(g)
        fnx.write(str(g))
        fnx.write("\n")
        g = (slope*(float(y[j])+k*interval)+inters)
        newys.append(g)
        fny.write(str(g))
        fny.write("\n")
        k = k+1
    j = j+2
    k=1

newxs.append(x)
newys.append(y)
```

but in the result, the points were denser everywhere except places that were previously empty and were supposed to get populated by the algorithm.

The graphs of the map [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5WXt.png) the application of the algorithm and
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZwx.png) (some proportions may vary but the main problem is the empty spot).

What is the approach that I could use in solving this problem? How to make the points distributed equally or maybe it's possible to calculate the COG with some other method?

My aim is that the amount of points shouldn't determine the COG, but rather determine the position of polygon sides - these are most important here, but obviously there is no database for them and it's harder to calculate the COG having a lot of linear functions and their ranges.

Comment: i am sure there are many relevant algorithms out there, but a naive way would be to identify the smallest distance between two adjacent points and then create points between all adjacent points such that each point is at-most minimum distance away from its neighbors. new points can just be on a straight line between adjacent points

Comment: yeah that's what I've tried in the above code, but for some reason it still produced a non-uniform distribution :(

Comment: Are the points in your dataset ordered? If so, you could connect adjacent ones with line segments and weight each segment by its length.

Comment: yes, they are ordered, do you think it'll be enough if I'll just find the midpoint of each line and treat it as a weighted point? Because a midpoint is the same for all possible orientations of a line and I wonder if I will have to take that into consideration or if it will just cancel out